# My Configure Your Dashboard stopped working after update

Tags: joomla, dashboard, dashlet

After updating civicrm from version 4.7.10 to 4.7.11, the configure fucton does not work any more.
There are no buttons any more in the configuration dahsboard:
[image: configuration dashboard] and drag and drop does not work anymore.
Meanwhile the Dashboard itself stays robust and in good health and keeps working okay.

I tried flushing all caches in the site, and sometimes this helps, and the dashboard then looks correct again and functions, but minutes later the image changes back to the button-less like the one in the image above.
I checked with Firebug and this reports a javascript error, with a very long text that I do not understand at all.
It is a pity because this has worked all the time in the versions before 4.7.11.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Can you also try clearing caches in your browser?

Comment: It looks like your site has some problems loading resources. Can you try https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0

Comment: The problems disappears when I set the dashlets in the closed position before clicking the Configure your dashboard button!
No idea how but it seems to help.
The panel of the civi news daslet when "rolled out" is not contained inside the admin tenplate in Joomla, I checked if this on itself breaks the configure yor dashboard page, but cannot find a direct relation.

Comment: I'll hazard a theory, which is that one or more of your dashlets contain css which interferes with the display of the configuration screen. Try removing all your dashlets and add them back one at a time to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CiviCRM 4.7.11 the issue could be solved by closing all widgets before configuring them. 
In version 4.7.12 the issue does not present itself anymore: solved.